# Фильтр для logger на c#

Tags: c#, filter, логирование

Вопрос заключается в том, что в рамках устранения Log Forgin типа XSS уязвимости необходимо все сообщения типа string, которые падают в _logger.Information(string message) предварительно до отправки прогонять через функцию очистки. Каким образом это можно организовать в общем для всех используемых логгеров в приложении на уровне общей логики ибо оборачивать message в каждом логгере - это будет страх и ужас. Само сообщение компанутеся из строк и взодных параметров эндпоинтов.
То есть вопрос, как строку, положенную в логгер, до логгирования прогнать через другой метод?

Comment: `.Replace("<", "&lt;")` или `Regex.Escape` или `Uri.EscapeUriString` или любой другой безопасный энкодинг полученной строки из инструментов какого-нибудь HTML-парсера

Comment: Вы не написали, какой именно логер используете. Вероятно, это система логирования Microsoft. Реализуете [custom logging provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider). В custom logger делаете любые желаемые проверки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, логгер от Microsoft. А данный кастомный провайдер можно будет приаттачить к уже используемым логгерам в сервисах?

Comment: Регистрируете в DI-контейнере свой провайдер вместо стандартного и всё.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov последний вопрос, как возвращать отфильтрованное значение? Или его возвращать не нужно, я просто не могу понять, что с этим значение нужно сделать. Его просто вывести командо Console.Log или нужно как-то записать его в state переменную, которая потом автоматом выведется? Просто я попробовал сереализовать эту satate переменную, почистить и потом десериализовать обратно, рассчитывая, что любой тип который приходит ссылочный и данная переменная потом выведется, но получит ошибку, тк тип который пришел FormattedLogValues и в него не получается десеарилизовать

Answer (score 0):

Для решения вашей задачи достаточно реализовать собственный форматтер логирования.
[Console log formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter)
Я взял пример из документации и лишь слегка изменил.

```
public sealed class CustomFormatter : ConsoleFormatter, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDisposable _optionsReloadToken;
    private CustomOptions _formatterOptions;

    public CustomFormatter(IOptionsMonitor<CustomOptions> options)
        // Case insensitive
        : base("customName") =>
        (_optionsReloadToken, _formatterOptions) =
            (options.OnChange(ReloadLoggerOptions), options.CurrentValue);

    private void ReloadLoggerOptions(CustomOptions options) =>
        _formatterOptions = options;

    public override void Write<TState>(
        in LogEntry<TState> logEntry,
        IExternalScopeProvider scopeProvider,
        TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        string? message =
            logEntry.Formatter?.Invoke(logEntry.State, logEntry.Exception);

        if (message is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        message = Filter(message, _formatterOptions);
        textWriter.WriteLine(message);
    }

    private string Filter(string message, CustomOptions _formatterOptions)
    {
        return message.Replace(_formatterOptions.OldValue, _formatterOptions.NewValue);
    }

    public void Dispose() => _optionsReloadToken?.Dispose();
}
```

Очистка происходит в методе `Filter`. Реализуйте там свою логику.

Так выглядит класс с настройками:

```
public class CustomOptions : ConsoleFormatterOptions
{
    public string? OldValue { get; set; }
    public string? NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

Метод расширения

```
public static class ConsoleLoggerExtensions
{
    public static ILoggingBuilder AddCustomFormatter(
        this ILoggingBuilder builder,
        Action<CustomOptions> configure) =>
        builder
            .AddConsole(options => options.FormatterName = "customName")
            .AddConsoleFormatter<CustomFormatter, CustomOptions>(configure);
}
```

Регистрируем наш форматтер. Код может различаться в зависимости хоста.

```
builder.Services.AddLogging(builder =>
    builder.AddCustomFormatter(options =>
    {
        options.OldValue = "#";
        options.NewValue = "";
    }));
```

В итоге сообщение `#Hello#` превращается в `Hello`.

---

При желании можно создать собственные провайдер и логгер.
[Implement a custom logging provider in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider)
Это даст больше возможностей, но сложнее в реализации.

Comment: А данный форматтер разве применяется для всех форм методов расширений? Я имею в виду, Log.Information, Log.Warning и пр. Просто, насколько я посмотрел делегат форматтера передается не во все методы расширения, но в методе Log ILogger он используется везде. Или же данный форматтер будет вызываться автоматически для всех типов логгеров (дебаг, консол и пр.)

Comment: я просто пытаюсь сейчас сделать через кастомный логгер, но мне приходится в кастомном логгере создавать объекты нескольких дефолтных логгеров и в них класть отфильтрованное значение, но ваш подход более правильный как по мне, только если его можно испльзовать для всех типов логгер провайдеров и методов расширений. Поверх уже готовых вызовов для логгирования